# why #submit not apply in form

Tags: 7, forms

I create a menu and in callback of it call this function

```
function floristdev_own_price_choice(){
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $form = node_add('customflower');
  $form['#submit'][]='floristdev_own_price_choice_sub';
      //      unset($form['#action']);
  dsm($form);
  return drupal_render($form);

}
function floristdev_own_price_choice_sub($form,$form_state){
    drupal_set_message('I called');
    dsm('blah blah');
}
```

but the `floristdev_own_price_choice_sub` never call ( I put die and drupal_set_message to test is it call ) 
where the problem, I am using drupal 7.

Comment: You need to do these `$form` changes in a form_alter() hook, as how you are doing them now is basically changing the form after the fact.  check out https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7 for more info

Comment: @Jimajamma , I know what is mean, but I need do it in this method

Comment: But that's not how form api is designed. There is a hook for that, and Drupal does not care what you think you need - you do it in the hook that's designed for the task, or it will not work. end of story. I can't change it. You can't change it. @Jimajamma can't change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what's happening...

- `node_add()` calls `drupal_get_form()` internally, which finalises the form and commits submit/validate handler data to the cache.
- You're modifying the data in the form array *after* it's been saved to cache.
- When the form submits, the page reloads and the API grabs the cached submit handlers from the store. As your submit function was never saved alongside that data, the API doesn't know about it.

You should use `hook_form_alter()` as already noted by Jimmajamma in the comments, then you won't have this problem at all.

Comment: I have similar theory. Form array is basically rebuilt on each page call. So if he adds submit handler in the call stack that *shows* form to an user, it is not added on the second load, when form is getting saved. So it can't work as it's not even there. Or is it the same theory, just written differently? Anyway, solution is still the same: use proper hook for the task.

Comment: I think that's a slightly different scenario to the cache one, but yeah, that's at least equally likely (if not more) to be the case

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your hook_menu to have `drupal_get_form` as callback and the form id as the argument:

```
function floristdev_menu() {
  $items['whatever/path'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('customflower_node_form'),
    ........ etc
  );
}
```

And do a hook_form_alter:

```
function floristdev_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'customflower_node_form') {
    $form['#submit'][]='floristdev_own_price_choice_sub';
  }
}
```

Now this should run:

```
function floristdev_own_price_choice_sub($form,$form_state){
  drupal_set_message('I called');
  dsm('blah blah');
}
```